# getting Error "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException"

Tags: ajax, laravel

```
                     $.ajax({

                        method: 'post',
                        url: '{{url("admin/append-course-pricebox-div")}}',
                        data: {_token:{{csrf_token()}},count:boxCount,workshop_id:$("#workshop_id").val()},
                        cache : false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.status == 'success') {
                                $('#success').html('Details are saved successfully.');
                                $('#success_popup .cd-popup').addClass('is-visible');
                            }else if(result.status =='blankTerm'){
                                $("#php-error_includes").show().html(result.message);
                            }
                            $('#preLoader').hide();
                        },
                        error: function (errors) {
                            $('#preLoader').hide();
                            var error = (JSON.parse(errors.responseText));
                            $.each(error.errors, function (key, val) {
                                $('#php-error_'+key).html(val);
                            });
                            $('.php-error').show();
                        }
                    });
```

when I post request it shows error and Google says it because of csrf error how I pass csrf_token to the controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please follow this steps
1.`"_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",` pass csrf token in request 
2.`<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">`
3.Detailed explaination can be found here[enter link description here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/csrf)

Comment: Please use correct json format 
"key":"token" like this hope its helpfull

{"_token":"{{csrf_token()}}",count:boxCount,workshop_id:$("#workshop_id").val()},

Comment: @SandhyaLathaBS try this code i an trying this working fine 

 $.ajax({
    url: '{{asset("/testurl")}}',
    dataType: "JSON",
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }, 
    type: "GET",
    data:{'search':value},
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});

Comment: i did exactly like this
                            method: 'post',
                            dataType: "JSON", 
                            headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
                            url: '{{url("admin/append-course-pricebox-div")}}',
                            data: {"_token":"{{csrf_token()}}","count":boxCount,"workshop_id":$("#workshop_id").val()},
                            cache : false,
                            contentType: false,
                            processData: false,

Comment: remove token from data and try this


'post', dataType: "JSON", headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') }, url: '{{url("admin/append-course-pricebox-div")}}', data: {"count":boxCount,"workshop_id":$("#workshop_id").val()}, cache : false, contentType: false,

Comment: Welcome @SandhyaLathaBS

Comment: am new to laravel so please excuse. value is not getting in the controller i just vardump request data it shows null

Comment: If are you using simple url without ajax use `dd()` for print value
if are you using ajax return response in json